images not found in in flask app/template
I am building an application using flask and everything works so far. Now I want to add an image as a background to a div like this:
<div style="width: 100%; height: 60em; justify-content: center; margin-top: 100px;">
  <div id="cc_overview">

  </div>
</div>

the css in the header for the cc_overview id looks like this:
#cc_overview {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: rgb(226, 167, 46);
        background-image: url('static/Screen21.png');
        border-radius: 20px;
        min-width: 20em;
        min-height: 20em;
        max-width: 40em;
        max-height: 40em;
        transform: translate(-10em,0);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

This is the (simplified) folder structure (I hope this is somewhat readable):
-application
|-app.py
|-static
||-Screen21.png
|-templates
||-page.html
EDIT: for some reason this gets collapsed into a single line, it should look like this:image
In the app I return page.html and that works but the console shows "GET https://abc.mydomain.com/cc/static/Screen21.png 404 (not found)"
I tried:

all kinds of different paths, absolute, relative, etc
putting the image in the templates folder
using differnet image formats (png and webp)
modifying .htaccess (but I have no clue what I am doing)
<img src="Screen21.webp"/> (same result)
probably some other things but I don't remember

I googled and tried all kinds of ideas for the past couple of hours so I hope anybody else has some ideas. Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT: Content (anonymized) of .htaccess file:
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/[username]/[full domain including subdomain]/application"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/[username]/virtualenv/[full domain including subdomain]/application/3.11/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
RewriteEngine On 
# RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv DBPW [some random characters here]
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
RewriteRule ^/.*$ - [F,L]


Make sure so the filename is correct, also check the casing of the filename. You could try to use style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='Screen21.png') }});" directly in your template. Might also be a good idea to update your question with the contents of your .htaccess file.

@Cyclonecode I made sure that the casing is correct for every image I tested and I also tried to use the line you suggested. I updated the post with the contents of the htaccess file
